# Why are all my object arrays overwriting themselves but the string array is not - java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

So I have this bit of java code which is for a hub system for a bunch of vents.  However the `VentNode` object is writing all the active values as the same as the list inserted value.  I created a `String array` to test if it would do the same, but the `String array` acted 'normally'.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadedEchoServer {

    private static final int port = 50103;
    private static final int timeout = 500;
    private VentNode[] nodes = new VentNode[256];
    private String[] ips = new String[256];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadedEchoServer server = new ThreadedEchoServer();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Vent system 10,000");
        server.scan();
        server.list();
        while(true){
            System.out.print("$ ");
            String msg = scanner.next();
            if(msg.equals("scan")){
                server.scan();
            }else if(msg.equals("on")){
                server.command(msg);
            }else if(msg.equals("off")){
                server.command(msg);
            }else if(msg.equals("list")){
                server.list();
            }else if(msg.equals("shutdown")){
                System.out.println("Shutting down");
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unknown command: " + msg);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    public void command(String cmd){
        for (VentNode node : nodes) {
            if (node != null ){
                Socket s;
                try {
                    s = new Socket(node.getSocket(),port);
                    new EchoThread(s,cmd);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Error connecting to node " + node.getId());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Error connecting to node " + node.getId());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void list(){
        for (String node : ips) {
            if (node != null )
                System.out.println("Socket " + node + ": " + node);
        }       
        for (VentNode node : nodes) {
            if (node != null )
                System.out.println("Socket " + node.getId() + ": " + node.getSocket());
        }
    }



    public void scan(){
        System.out.println("Scanning for vents. This will take a minute.");
        try {
            String currentIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
            String subnet = getSubnet(currentIP);
                for (int i=13;i<42;i++){
                    Socket socket;
                    String host = subnet + i;
                    if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                        //System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                        try {
                            socket = new Socket(host, port);
                            System.out.println("Adding vent: " + i);
                            new EchoThread(socket);
                            nodes[i] = new VentNode(host,i,0,0);
                            ips[i] = host;
                        }catch(Exception s){
                            //System.out.println("failed to connect to " + host + " on port " + port);
                        }
                    }

                }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private String getSubnet(String currentIP) {
        int firstSeparator = currentIP.lastIndexOf("/");
        int lastSeparator = currentIP.lastIndexOf(".");
        return currentIP.substring(firstSeparator+1, lastSeparator+1);
    }
}
```

**and the outputs are as follows:**

```
Vent system 10,000
Scanning for vents. This will take a minute.
Adding vent: 14
Adding vent: 41
Socket x.x.x.14: x.x.x.14
Socket x.x.x.41: x.x.x.41
Socket 41: x.x.x.41
Socket 41: x.x.x.41
$
```

as you can see in the last two outputs it writes 41 for both vent 14 and vent 41.  I can toiled for hours trying to figure out why this is happening.  I thought I would stop by and ask the experts.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Please show the code for your class ventNode.

Comment: And please, stick to the Java Naming Conventions: class names **must** start with an uppercase letter. `ventNode` must be `VentNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as you can see in the last two outputs it writes 41 for both vent 14 and vent 41.

At this point its just an educated guess but most likely you declared the fields in you class `ventNode` *static* which means that their content is shared between all instances of that class.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the issue.  `private VentNode[] nodes = new VentNode[256];`

Comment: @Squirrel-Moose: My doubt is not about the array... Please show the code for your class `VentNode`!

Comment: So you are correct.  I looked at my ventNode class and ALL the variables are static....  I changed them and now the code works! <3